# I am having ArrayList containing String[], If i add new string[] into list, it also modifed previously added string [] objects

Tags: java, android

I am adding string[] into Arraylist, But when i try to retrieve value from it, something wrong happening. and previous values of arraylist getting updated with new entry(String[])
Expected Output :
first , sec
1, 2
one, two

Current Output :
one, two
one, two 
one, two

below is the code.

```
   ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
   String[] temp ={"First","Sec"};
   list.add(temp);
   temp[0] ="1";temp[1]="2";
   list.add(temp);
   temp[0] ="one";temp[1]="two";
   list.add(temp);

   printLog(list);
```

here is the print method

```
   private void printLog(ArrayList<String[]> result) {
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        Log.d(TAG,"I="+i);
        String[] temp = result.get(i);
        Log.d(TAG,temp[0]+","+temp[1]+"\n");
    }

}
```

Any suggessions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are adding reference of an array object to the list. You need to create new array each time.

```
   String[] temp ={"First","Sec"};
   list.add(temp);
   temp=new String[2];
   temp[0] ="1";temp[1]="2";
   list.add(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate a new String[] array value before adding the 2nd one to the list. Right now you are overwriting the values in the array which is why only the last ones appear.

Comment: when i am trying to enter 1,2(second add in my code), why first,sec getting updated, as it already save in arraylist

Comment: Your ArrayList is saving a pointer to temp in all 3 entries. So they are all pointing to the same object. That's why you need to create a new object each time.

Answer (score 0):

It appears like you're passing the arrays (not the `ArrayList`) by reference. This means that when you have multiple ways to access the data, they all point to the same location in RAM, meaning that changes are seemingly propagated.

To solve this problem, I would suggest either creating a `new String[]` or using the `Arrays.copyOf(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

This questions is beeing asked pretty often. ArrayList doesn't make a copy of the objects you add to it. It just stored references to these objects. So, if you add, as you're doing, the same array twice, the list just holds two references to the same array.

You have to create a new array for each element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with same same problem when adding list to a HashMap. Actually it adds a reference to that list/array while you are working in the same function. So you need to change String[] name each time; in order to add in list.

Answer (score 0):

`It seems that Atring array is initialized once but its value is overridden three times.` initially String[] temp contains `{"First","Sec"};` then it became `{"1","2"}` by writing   `temp[0] ="1"; temp[1]="2";` and finally it became `{"one", "two"}` by writing `temp[0] ="one"; temp[1]="two";`

In this case each time the value of the same array is change. **you need to initialize** `(by writing temp = new String[2];)`**the array each time** so that it will be treated as new array not the the same

```
String[] temp ={"First","Sec"};
               list.add(temp);
               temp = new String[2];
               temp[0] ="1";
               temp[1]="2";
               list.add(temp);
               temp = new String[2];
               temp[0] ="one";
               temp[1]="two";
               list.add(temp);
```